# What methods do you use to analyze / define attack surface for a software?

Tags: security-testing

It is good to define an attack surface before security testing.

Different places to attack:

- Open pages & services (like login)
- Attack to underlying layers/servers/etc
- Attack to other users
- ...

Different kind of attacks:

- Owasp list attacks (XSS, injection, ...)
- Burte force, DoS

Different risks...

So I was wondering what methods do you use?
Attack surface analyzing is a part of for example Microsoft's The Security Development Lifecycle (SDL).

Answer (score 3):

There is Microsoft's own [Attack Surface Analyzer Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_Surface_Analyzer)
which was first released in 2011, runs on Vista/Win7/Win Server 2008 and generates reports in HTML format.

> Attack Surface Analyzer is all in one tool for analysis of changes
>   made to the various parts of the attack surface of Windows 6 series
>   Operating System (includes Windows Vista and Windows 7). Using this
>   one tool, you can analyze the changes made to the Registry, File
>   permissions, Windows IIS Server, GAC assemblies and a lot more can be
>   done[7]. According to Microsoft, it is the same tool in use by the
>   engineers of the security team at Microsoft to analyze the effects of
>   software installation on the Windows Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think that the important first step of any security test is to build a good threat model. The threat modelling process if done correctly should surface a lot of the potential areas for attack.